# Does any version of .NET have a Random.Shared property accessible through code?

Tags: c#, .net

I was using the .net source browser [here](https://source.dot.net/) and looked up the `Random` class to discover that it has a `Shared` property on it that gives access to a thread-safe implementation. I needed something similar, so I tried accessing it in my code, but the Random class seems to not have any static properties on it, and I could find no mention (outside of this source) on the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random) of such a property.

I also wasn't able to figure out whether source.dot.net points to an official version of .Net (and if it does, what version), however the tool that generated it is also used for [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Is there a `Shared` property available on System.Random in any version of .Net, and is source.dot.net a legitimate reference for .net source code?

Comment: I would go straight to the source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-5.0. That shows only Methods available, so I'd say no, there is no `Shared` property.  Note that document has a section about [thread safety](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=net-5.0#the-systemrandom-class-and-thread-safety) you may find edifying.

Comment: It was added on [April 1st](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/1fea73f457d94d8d71511a61053ec9f84a1348ea#diff-6fa7e54f57878bb019a11332aeeb42c75430a0ac87c78cdfa9ce382137b3d851), probably sees the light of day at the .NET6 release.

Comment: Thank you! I looked in the System.Private.CoreLib under the coreclr folder, but didn't find the one under libraries!

Comment: [Here's the issue covering this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/43887). Note that https://referencesource.microsoft.com has the sources for the old .NET Framework, and not the new .NET Core (those are in github.com/dotnet/runtime/).

Comment: new source browser is here https://source.dot.net/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Random.Shared` appeared first in **.NET 6**

Answer (score 1):

> Provides a thread-safe Random instance that may be used concurrently from any thread.

Here's a cool way to use it in a simple Parallel op!

```cs
var random = Random.Shared;

async IAsyncEnumerable<int[]> SimStreamAsync(int value = 0)
{
  while (true)
  {
    await Task.Delay(random.Next(5, 20));
    yield return new int[]
      { ++value, ++value, ++value, ++value, ++value };
  }
}

await Parallel.ForEachAsync(SimStreamAsync(),
  new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, process);

async ValueTask process(int[] numbers, CancellationToken token)
{
  await Task.Delay(random.Next(500, 1000));
  Console.WriteLine(numbers.Last());
}
```